# android browser input scale issue

Tags: android, scale

I'm developing a mobile web-application. And I faced with the problem: when I focus any input text field on the page, the page scales (zooms), and besides only in android browser. Setting **user-scalable=no** in *meta* tag has not solved the problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Here is my veiwport:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this , it works fine for me in galaxy pop

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In your java code try this,

```
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

Try this and let me know what happen..

Comment: It is asp .net mvc application. So I guess it is some tricky js needed or some extra parameters for viewport.

Comment: Are you developing using Phonegape?

Comment: Look at [Is there a way to disable the zoom feature on input fields in webview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702805/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-zoom-feature-on-input-fields-in-webview) and [Scale the WebView to fit the device](http://uihacker.blogspot.in/2011/01/android-phonegap-scale-webview-to-fit.html)